# What is the proper function from the java Stripe api to call to complete express account connection?

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I am creating a marketplace with many sellers and buyers using Stripe. Our connected accounts are Express accounts.  In order to create a new account, I am following these instructions: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts

First, the user calls  "https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=&scope=read_write". This takes the user to a Stripe page for account creation. This works fine. Upon completing this Stripe form, Stripe redirects the visitor to whichever page we specify and includes a query parameter in the url. This works fine. To complete the account creation, I understand I need to send a post request to https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token with three values: 
1. client_secret -which is our Stripe account's API key; 
2. code, which is the query parameter that Stripe returned, and 
3. grant_type.

When I submit this post request in Postman, it works...

```
POST https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token 
{
"client_secret": <secret key>,
"code": "<query parameter from Stripe redirect url>",
"grant_type": "authorization_code"
}
```

How do I make this post request from our website's Java server code using the Stripe Java library? Which class in the Java Stripe library is meant for this? I don't see one, but it should exist somewhere because this is a common use case.

Thank you,
Gideon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an OAuth package in stripe-java, [this test](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/8aebffd7b3d9a9ad953efd4bdd62bf5daea2c623/src/test/java/com/stripe/net/OAuthTest.java#L69-L73) shows an example of using it.

```
final Map<String, Object> tokenParams = new HashMap<>();
tokenParams.put("grant_type", "authorization_code");
tokenParams.put("code", "this_is_an_authorization_code");

final TokenResponse resp = OAuth.token(tokenParams, null);
```